# Changing the pytest parameters on re run

Tags: pytest

I have some data parameterizing tests as a dictionary within the test file. The data is picked up pytest_generate_tests and then parameterized. I have timestamps and some random data within said dictionary to prevent repeating values. This works fine, until the test fails. The same data is used on the re run since pytest_generate_tests is only run once which causes problems. Is there a way to change the parameters?

Comment: Please add a small, reproducible sample to elaborate on the exact problem.

Comment: Check out [mcve] for hints on how to do that.